# How can I read/write an array of objects inside a PostgreSQL row? (GoLang)

Tags: postgresql, go

I defined this types in GoLang:

```
type Comment struct {
    Id          int
    User        string
    Email       string
    Date        string
    Comment     string
}

type Post struct {
    Id          int
    Special     bool
    Title       string
    Date        string
    Content     string
    Image       string
    Comments    []Comment
}
```

I need to know how to modify this code:

```
OpenDB()
rows, _ := cn.Query(`SELECT id, date, title, special, content, image
            FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $1
            OFFSET $2`, fmt.Sprint(limit), fmt.Sprint(offset))
posts := []Post{}
for rows.Next() {
  post := Post{}
  e := rows.Scan(&post.Id, &post.Date, &post.Title,
                &post.Special, &post.Content, &post.Image)
  if e != nil {
    panic(e)
  }
  posts = append(posts, post)
}
```

To allow reading comments. And also, how I can modify:

```
OpenDB()
_, e = cn.Exec(`INSERT INTO
                posts(date, title, special, content, image)
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`, date, title, special, content, image)
if e != nil {
    panic(e)
}
defer CloseDB()
```

To allow writting an empty array of comments.

Finally I would be grateful if someone tell me how can I write single comments into an existing post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your database schema.

---

If `Comment` has its own table you will have to loop over all comments in a `Post` and insert them after you have have inserted the `Post`. `cn.Exec` should return a [Result](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Result) which can be used to get the last inserted ID like:

```golang
result, err := cn.Exec(...)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

id, err := result.LastInsertId()
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

You can now use the ID of your post as a foreign key.

---

If you are using a [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html) column to store your comments you should define a custom type as alias for `[]Comment` and make the type implement [sql.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) and [driver.Valuer](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Valuer).

```golang
type Comment struct {
    Id          int
    User        string
    Email       string
    Date        string
    Comment     string
}

type Comments []Comment

// Make the Comments type implement the driver.Valuer interface. This method
// simply returns the JSON-encoded representation of the struct.
func (c Comments) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(c)
}

// Make the Comments type implement the sql.Scanner interface. This method
// simply decodes a JSON-encoded value into the struct fields.
func (c *Comments) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    var b []byte
    switch t := value.(type) {
    case []byte:
        b = t
    case string:
        b = string(t)
    default:
        return errors.New("unknown type")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &c)
}
```

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem with different tables for posts and comments. Thanks so much!